# Is there a name for expressions of the form $n^n$?

Tags: terminology

$n*n$ is a *square* number. Is there a corresponding descriptive term for $n^n$?

*Auto-power*? *2nd-order tetration*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was the name "Wexzal" introduced. Fantini/Kloepfer discussed it in that way:

> This book is about the solution to and properties of the Coupled
>   Exponent equation (y=x^x). The solution to this equation is called the
>   "Coupled Root function".

(but I did not read that name elsewhere, so it seems that name didn't make it through the world)

"Wexzal", Jay A. Fantini Gilbert C. Kloepfer (~1999)

online available, maybe you must employ the wayback-machine.

---

In he tetration-forum it became fairly common to call the iteration of iterated exponentiation/powertower "height", so we would call it "powertower of height 2" or some easier-to-speak variants.

---

ANother hint, which you possibly have not come across yet: you could also look at R. Munafo's site who invented some expressions for iterated exponentiation and resulting "really big" numbers.

Comment: That source has: _In 1981, the term "Wexzal" was defined to mean "Coupled Root of 10^x"_. The term that source uses for $x^x$ is "coupled exponent". It says alternate names are "Self-exponential" and "Second-order Towering exponent". [pdf](http://go.helms-net.de/math/divers/WexZal.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I've most often heard simply "$n$ to the $n$". The term "hyperpower" is sometimes used for tetration, so I guess you could say "$n$ to the second hyperpower".

Answer (score 0):

There is no common term for $n^n$. I think a reasonable term if needed for casual use would be *super square* based on:

- *superexponentation* is an alternative name for [tetration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration)
- *super-root* is a name for the inverse of tetration (along with *super-logarithm*)
- *super square-root* is the name for $x$ in the equality $y=x^x$